# What is wrong with my script?

Tags: python, texturing, scripting

I was searching for a way to make a script that will help me increase my work speed, in other words, I tried to make a script that duplicates an object, then set it a texture each time and then loops, but when I run the script, it makes 1 dupe and doesn't change the texture.
additionally: when the script runs without the changing texture part, it works as intended:

```
import bpy 
num = 0
num2 = -4
for i in range (0,10):
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=0,mode='TRANSLATION') 
    obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
    obj.location.y = obj.location.y + 10.24
    num = num + 4
    num2 = num2 + 4  
    bpy.data.images['Texture.4.-12.'+str(num2)+'.DDS'].filepath = 'Texture.4.-12.'+str(num)+'.DDS'
```

from the answer that i've got, i've advanced to this:

```
import bpy 
num = 0
num2 = -4
for i in range (0,10):
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=0,mode='TRANSLATION') 
    obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
    obj.location.y = obj.location.y + 10.24
    num = num + 4
    num2 = num2 + 4  
    prev_image = bpy.data.images.load( "D:\World\Textures\Terrain\Texture.4.-12."+str(num)+".DDS" )
    image = bpy.data.images.load( "D:\World\Textures\Terrain\Texture.4.-12."+str(num2)+".DDS" )
    bpy.data.images[str(prev_image)].filepath = str(image)
```

Comment: If only one duplicate, that mean there is an exception thrown. Should look in the console to check what it says.

Comment: hello, thanks for answer, the console outputs this:
bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=False, mode='TRANSLATION')
bpy.ops.text.run_script()
Python script failed, check the message in the system console
(it does not select wrong line)

Comment: You should have more information in the system console: use the Window menu then "Toggle System Console".

Comment: thanks, system console prints this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\That Pony\Documents\untitled.blend\Text", line 10, in <module>
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "D:\\World\\Textures\\Terrain\\Texture.4.-12.0.DDS" not found'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
(if you ask, texture itself does exist)

Comment: But the image in Blender memory does not exist, so you cannot access to bpy.data.images["your image"]. You should image = bpy.data.images.load( "your path" ) instead.

Comment: is the example added in post right? it still prints me that the image doesn't exist, without str() on last line, gives error that it should be given int or string not Image

Comment: So, it looks like you are trying to get the file path of the image stored in Blender memory with bpy.data.images[str(prev_image)].filepath but str(prev_image) is turning the image you saved into a string. It seems like you need to remove the last line and rather do something like obj.texture = image to set the image texture to the image you created, which would be the simplest.
Note that I've barely scripted in Blender, so I don't know the Blender Python properties and such, but I'm familiar with Python and Blender. ie, I might have no clue what I'm talking about, so feel free to correct me.

Comment: thanks for answer but obj.texture didn't get me anything, or i guess i didnt use it correctly? i'd like to see example, cuz it looks like i cannot make it myself